# Two equivalent vectors groups

Tags: vectors

Let $v_1,\cdots,v_n$ and $w_1,\cdots w_n$ to be two equivalent vectors groups in $\mathbb{R}^m$, that is, $v_i$ can be linearly expressed by $w_1,\cdots w_n$, and $w_j$ can be linearly expressed by $v_1,\cdots,v_n$. Can we show that there exists an invertible matrix $P$ such that $$(w_1,\cdots w_n)=(v_1,\cdots,v_n)P?$$

It is easy if $P$ is some matrix, but can we choose $P$ to be invertible?

Notice that $v_1,\cdots,v_n$ may be linearly dependent.